# Centering RadialProgress.RadialProgressView in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I have a RadialProgress.RadialProgressView (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.RadialProgress/) in my Xamarin.Android app. I would like to center the RadialProgressView in the remaining space. To do this, I did the following:

```
<RadialProgress.RadialProgressView android:id="@+id/rpvTimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_column="0" android:layout_row="1" android:layout_columnSpan="3"/>
```

However, it seems to be treating the layout_width as if it was match_parent. If I set layout_width to a fixed value, it will center it, but that will cause one of the following (depending on the result from rowWeight):

1. If the fixed width is larger than the resulting height, extra horizontal space is added, therefore causing the RadialProgressView to not be centered.
2. If the fixed width is less than the resulting height, the RadialProgressView does not use the full available height, which is what I want it to do.

Is there a way to make RadialProgressView use only the necessary width? Manually calculating the values seems unnecessary, but it is the only solution I can think of. Any ideas?

Comment: I had done a demo and found that the RadialProgressView is a circle. So the smaller one between its height and weight will work. In addition,that the wrap content is according to the size of child view which usually have a default  or exact value. I don't know the RadialProgressView has one or not.

Comment: I haven't found the exact answer yet, but I am working on creating a custom RadialProgressView and overriding OnMeasure. I have found that using a single line like:

Comment: I haven't found the exact answer yet, but I am working on creating a custom RadialProgressView and overriding OnMeasure. I have found that using a single line like:
`this.SetMeasuredDimension(400, 400);`
does what I want, except for the fact that it is not dynamic. In order to make it dynamic, I have found that if I use
`int height = View.MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec);`
I can get the height, but unfortunately this value is 0 until the final pass. I am having trouble getting it to work by using the condition of height==0, but I think OnMeasure is the key to the answer.

Comment: If you custom a view and override the OnMeasure method of it, you need to give it a default size such as what you do. But if you do so,  setting the default value as the size directly is easier.